# How to use custom java object as request param in Rest client?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, feign

I have Rest API and feign client from different service to invoke it. My client method is as follows

```
@GetMapping("/{employerId}/data")
List<Data> searchData(final @PathVariable("employerId") String employerId,
final @RequestParam(required = false) DataQueryVO dataQuery);
```

My API as follows. I can invoke this API with postman to get correct data, but in java it's always get fields inside `DataQueryVO` null even-though i set the fileds.

```
@GetMapping("/{employerId}/data")
public @ResponseBody List<Data> searchData(@PathVariable String employerId,
final DataQueryVO dataQuery)
```

My requirement is to have custom java object as request param in REST api and invoke it from feign client. How can i do that ?